# Jmeter API Testing Report Generation

Tags: jmeter, report, jmeter-plugins

I am using JMeter for api testing. How can I generate pass/fail report of my testing? Is there any plugin available? I just want to know either my test pass or fail and import it.

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok you should accept it and upvote so that it's useful to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have not figured it yet and for the reference to other users, you can use the following command line options to generate an HTML report. The report will be generated at the end of the test run. Note that the report_dir should not exist and report will not be generated if the test is stopped with signal interrupts.

```
./jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l test.jtl -e -o report_dir
```

Answer (score 1):

Jmeter Contains Listeners which can publish you the results of your test, from which you can analyse whether your test is pass or fail.

**Thread Group-(Right Click)--->Add-->Listeners**(Which contains various types, you can select based on your requirement)

Answer (score 1):

Since JMeter 3.0 , an HTML report is generated at end of test provided you follow this documentation:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I went through the link you had mentioned but I didn't get the solution. I want the HTML report like mentioned in the link. I copied the line of codes from report.properties to user.properties.I restarted the jmeter. I didn't see any Dashboard. Am I missing something?

Comment: yes if you just updated user.properties or jmeter.properties then it means you didn't read carefully the doc. You need to add command line options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of these in the menu to view the result.
**Thread Group > Add > Listeners**
If you are looking for detailed report, i suggest LoadSophia (Loadosophia.org) which will help in better understanding of the report.
You have to generate the jtl file (jtl file is generated while running jmeter from terminal and setting output directory) and uploading the jtl file to LoadSophia.

Answer (score 0):

In general JMeter automatically. treats samplers with [HTTP Status Code](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) above 400 as failed.

In addition if you expect some data to be in the response body (or vice versa) you can apply i.e.

- [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) - to check whether specified text is present in response
- [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) - to ensure that request duration does not exceed some threshold
- etc.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide to learn more about conditionally failing JMeter samplers basing on different criteria